# Share a windows file share between 2 networks

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

We have our main network windows domain, but we also have some standalone machines that aren't on our domain, we want to setup a separate network, 192.168.2.xxx for the standalone machines to use. We have a storage server 2008 machine setup on both networks, it is a member of our domain. How could I go about making a file share available to computers on the domain as well as on the 192.168.2.xxx network?

Clarification: I currently can't access any windows file shares on the server from the 192.168.2.xxx network. I can ping the server and remote desktop to it. I can access all shares/normal behavior on the domain side. Is there anything I need to do to be able to use the windows shares from the 192.168.2.xxx network?

Comment: Are these standalone machines the same physical network?

Comment: Yes, both networks are physical, the server has 4 nics, 2 on the domain and 2 on the "Stand alone".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal practice is to create one or more domain accounts to be used for accessing shared resources on domain machines. Users on the non-domain machines (standalone really means they're not on a network) use those accounts to access the shares. The accounts can be locked down as much as you require to prevent them being used for other purposes.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. I made the question a little more specific, I currently can't access the server from the 192.168.2.xxx network, do I need any routing statements in the shared sever?

Comment: And in response to the "Stand alone comment" these computers are stand alone currently I'm testing an network that I'll connect them to, but I still think of them as standalone because they aren't on the domain.

Comment: @Peter, It's worth checking the routing on both server and client but I suspect the firewall on the server may be the culprit, as it would most likely be treating the other network as untrusted.

Comment: I don't know much about routing, I deal mostly with switches. Could you give an example of a route statement that would do something similar? I have the firewall off on the server but I still can't get any to windows shares.

Comment: @Peter, as I don't know anything about your network the best I can suggest is to open a cmd window and type `route /?`. You're going to want to use `route add` to add the appropriate routes.